# vim and ctags, multiple definitions with same signature not found

Tags: c++, vim, ctags

I have a simple c++ file like this:

```
class SomeClass
{
    void SomeMethod() {};
};

class AnotherClass
{
    void SomeMethod() {};
};
```

If I generate a ctags file with `ctags -R *` I got:

```
AnotherClass    main.cpp    /^    class AnotherClass$/;"    c   file:
SomeClass   main.cpp    /^    class SomeClass$/;"   c   file:
SomeMethod  main.cpp    /^        void SomeMethod() {};$/;" f   class:AnotherClass  typeref:typename:void   file:
SomeMethod  main.cpp    /^        void SomeMethod() {};$/;" f   class:SomeClass typeref:typename:void   file:
```

As you can see, there is no difference in the entries for the definition of `SomeMethod` and as this in vim `tf` and `tn` shows always first definition in file.

I also can add a line number with `ctags --fields=+n *`
which results in:

```
...
AnotherClass    main.cpp    /^    class AnotherClass$/;"    c   line:6  file:
SomeClass   main.cpp    /^    class SomeClass$/;"   c   line:1  file:
SomeMethod  main.cpp    /^        void SomeMethod() {};$/;" f   line:3  class:SomeClass typeref:typename:void   file:
SomeMethod  main.cpp    /^        void SomeMethod() {};$/;" f   line:8  class:AnotherClass  typeref:typename:void   file:
```

But vim also jumps always to the first definition of `SomeMethod` if I use `ta SomeMethod` and `tn`

I am using ctags in this version:

> Universal Ctags 0.0.0(2614dbe1), Copyright (C) 2015 Universal Ctags Team
>   Universal Ctags is derived from Exuberant Ctags.
>   Exuberant Ctags 5.8, Copyright (C) 1996-2009 Darren Hiebert
>     Compiled: Sep  5 2019, 13:10:38
>     URL: https://ctags.io/
>     Optional compiled features: +wildcards, +regex, +iconv, +option-directory, +xpath, +yaml, +packcc

and vim is:

> VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 Patch 1-1713

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a simple solution myself:

```
ctags --excmd=number *
```

did the job.

In the third column of the tags file we find the excmd which vim uses to find the place in the file.

```
SomeMethod  main.cpp    /^        void SomeMethod() {};$/;" f   line:8  class:AnotherClass  typeref:typename:void   file:
```

becomes

```
SomeMethod  main.cpp    8;" f   line:8  class:AnotherClass  typeref:typename    :void   file:
```

Now vim did not search for the expression which is duplicated in the tags file but simply goes to the line which is in the excmd.

Comment: This has the problem if you add lines into the file, line numbers will change.

Comment: @geza Quite clear! Having a outdated tags file can result in wrong findings. Changing the function signature will result in not findable lines in the default case. A perfect solution will something like "find the nth line of regexp". But this will only work if we can't have the same regexp somewhere else in the file like in comments. Simple solution: Wrong finding: generate tags file again. Even for large projects it takes only some seconds. No problem!

Answer (score 2):

Try `--excmd=combine`. It prepends a line number to a pattern.

```
$ cat /tmp/main.cpp 
class SomeClass
{
    void SomeMethod() {};
};

class AnotherClass
{
    void SomeMethod() {};
};
$ ./ctags -o - --excmd=combine /tmp/main.cpp
AnotherClass    /tmp/main.cpp   5;/^class AnotherClass$/;"  c   file:
SomeClass   /tmp/main.cpp   0;/^class SomeClass$/;" c   file:
SomeMethod  /tmp/main.cpp   2;/^    void SomeMethod() {};$/;"   f   class:SomeClass typeref:typename:void   file:
SomeMethod  /tmp/main.cpp   7;/^    void SomeMethod() {};$/;"   f   class:AnotherClass  typeref:typename:void   file:
$ ./ctags -o - --excmd=combine -B /tmp/main.cpp
AnotherClass    /tmp/main.cpp   7;?^class AnotherClass$?;"  c   file:
SomeClass   /tmp/main.cpp   2;?^class SomeClass$?;" c   file:
SomeMethod  /tmp/main.cpp   4;?^    void SomeMethod() {};$?;"   f   class:SomeClass typeref:typename:void   file:
SomeMethod  /tmp/main.cpp   9;?^    void SomeMethod() {};$?;"   f   class:AnotherClass  typeref:typename:void   file:
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need either:

- to pass the right number to `:tag` & co,
- or to use `:tselect`
- or to use a plugin that'll help distinguish/select the overload you're interested in (like my old [lh-tags](https://github.com/luchermitte/lh-tags) plugin)
- or a more modern solution like a LSP server: lately I've found coc+ccls to be quite nice as it'll know from the context which is the exact overload under the cursor, which is impossible with tag based solutions.

Comment: You didn't catch the point: I walk through the tag list and get always the SAME line in the file. I know to navigate with `tf` and `tn` as already written in my question. But all this ends in the SAME line of the source code. As you can see in the tags file, both lines are identical! Adding the line number is ignored by vim!

Comment: @Klaus Language server should fix that, I'd recommend you take a look at that as an alternative to using ctags.

Comment: @Klaus. My mistake, I've misread your question. Looks like a bug, open a bug report/issue on vim repository on github them.

Comment: Seems not to be a bug. My understanding is: The tags file presents a excmd in the third column of the tags file. If the line is absolutely identical, vim has no chance to find the correct one. But ctags excepts another excmd, simply "go to line". See my own answer.